# How to remove a file included in parent theme with locate_template() via child theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

In my theme I use `locate_template()` to load the various parts of my functions library. I'm looking for a way to not include one of those files when using a child theme. I tried adding `locate_template('same_file_name.php', false);` to my child theme's functions.php but it is still included.

CLARIFICATION EDIT: I don't want to prevent this file from being used by child themes. In general I want this file to be included when I am using a child theme. I am looking for something to add to a child theme when I don't want to use it.

Comment: Does `same_file_name.php` exist in you child theme?

Comment: In general (ie in the starter child theme I always start from) yes, but in the cases were I don't need it I can delete it.

Comment: Upvoted the answer by @G.M because I think you are going to need something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution that takes inspiration from both answers by **@Milo** and **@toscho**.

create your own function to load template, e.g.

```
if ( ! function_exists('my_locate_template') ) {
  function my_locate_template( $template = '', $load = false, $once = true ) {
    $filtered = apply_filters('allow_child_load_' . $template, true);
    if ( ! is_child_theme() || $filtered ) return locate_template($template, $load, $once);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then in your parent theme load files using `my_locate_template('same_file_name.php')`.

In this way your files will be always loaded in parent theme and when using child theme, you can use the filter to exclude some files.

```
add_filter('allow_child_load_disallow-this.php', '__return_false');
```

and after that the file `disallow-this.php`, will not be loaded in that child theme.

Also note the function is wrapped in `if (! function_exists('my_locate_template') ) {` so, if you want, you can completely replace it in a child theme.

Simple, flexible, and with comfortable defaults.

Comment: This would remove the file whenever a child theme is used. I need to be able to choose to remove it from specific child themes. Updating question to make this more clear.

Comment: @JPollock by default it removes the file in every child themes, but in child theme `functions.php` via the `allow_child_load_{$file}` filter, you can choose to allow the loading of specific files. So in every child themes you have control upon every file loading or not.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like the file to be included by default. In specific cases I want to remove it.

Comment: @JPollock now the function is *opt-out*: by defaults it include files, and via filter you can exclude some files.

Comment: Brilliant stuff. This works perfectly for files in the theme, but what about if the file I was trying to disallow was in a subdirectory?

Comment: @JPollock `add_filter('allow_child_load_SubdirName/FileName.php', '__return_false');` is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1):

You could offer a filter for these files in your parent theme. Then you can decide in each child theme separately which files should be loaded:

```
$files_to_include = array(
    'foo.php',
    'bar.php'
);
$files_to_include = apply_filters(
    get_template() . '_files_to_include',
    $files_to_include
);

if ( ! empty ( $files_to_include ) )
{
    foreach ( $files_to_include as $file )
        locate_template( $file );
}
```

In a child theme you can remove some files from that array now:

```
add_filter( get_template() . '_files_to_include', function( $files )
{
    $bar_key = array_search( 'bar.php', $files );

    if ( FALSE !== $bar_key )
        unset( $files[ $bar_key ] );

    return $files;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `locate_template` call in a check for [`is_child_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_child_theme) in your parent theme so it will be ignored:

```
if( ! is_child_theme() ){
    locate_template( ... );
}
```

Comment: This would remove the file whenever a child theme is used. I need to be able to choose to remove it from specific child themes. Updating question to make this more clear.